# Flutter GoogleMap Widget creates lingering artifacts when I change screen

Tags: flutter, google-maps, controller, dispose

I've got a GoogleMap widget sandwiched amongst other Widgets on a screen. If I Navigate away, Flutter doesn't dispose of the Map before the new page loads. This is doubly annoying because I have animated a profile picture with a Hero Widget, to fly across the screen & 'Jazz' the page transition. But with the Map artifact taking a few extra beats to vanish the whole transition looks shoddy. This happens in both the Android emulator and on an Android device.

I've tried Googling and Stackoverflow to dispose of the Map widget's controller, but that's not a thing seemingly.

`final Completer<GoogleMapController> myGoogleMapController = new Completer<GoogleMapController>();`

Bit of a funky controller right?

This wouldn't be a problem if the map widget was full-screen, it'd just take a few extra beats for the screen to change. But it's not full screen, it's one widget amongst many.

I want the Google map Widget to disappear promptly, or at least more promptly.
Any thoughts on perf-ing it up?

Comment: I have the exact same issue. It seems it was ok on `google_maps_flutter: 2.0.6` but with `2.2.5` I have the issue. Any solution?

Comment: Hey, I am also getting the same. Did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: No, sorry. Maybe a cross to be bourne till a plugin revision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this by wrapping the GoogleMap widget in a **Visibility** widget.

```
SizedBox(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 300,
          child: Visibility(
            visible: screenOpen, child:
            GoogleMap(
            myLocationEnabled: true,
            mapType: MapType.normal,
            initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
              target: LatLng(widget.job.latitude!, widget.job.longitude!),
              zoom: 14.8,
            ),
            onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
            circles: circles!,
          ))),
```

screenOpen is a class variable:

```
bool screenOpen = true;
```

When the user seeks to pop the screen, I first flip Visibility's visible bool, then pop the screen...

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          setState(() {
            screenOpen = false;
          });
          Navigator.of(context).pop(widget.job);
          return true;
    },
    child: Scaffold(
```

PERHAPS key to its success was giving the GoogleMap Widget a SizedBox parent, with a defined height. Thus when its child disappears, the SizedBox holds every Widget beneath it in place, preventing a major screen redraw as widgets lower down, leap up. Instead, I believe, Flutter simply has to paint the background in where the map widget was.

EXTRAS: I use a key on the Visibility widget, just in case it matters.
I also set `screenOpen = true;` in every invocation of `initState()`

Improvements welcome.

If the GoogleMap plugin starts disposing of itself promptly on-screen exit **PLEASE POST AN ALERT AS AN ANSWER TO THIS QUESTION**.

Comment: As of 2023-07, still seeing artefacts. Your solution was helpful. WillPopScope didn't fit my use case, but the concept of wrapping in a Visibility (key seems unnecessary) and setting to false just before navigation begins works regardless. Thanks!

Comment: i have mine in a tab view and it makes the layout stutter when switching tabs

Answer (score 1):

I also have this issue but my map is in a TabBarView i solved it by holding a reference to the tab index and using a similar trick of just hiding the map when we aren't on that page

```
Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: context.colors.secondaryContainer,
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(16),
          ),
        ),
        height: 300,
        child: Provider.of<TabControl>(context).index == 0 ? const Map(height: 300) : null,
      ),
```